# what is the difference between numb, dope, anesthetize, drug?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-difference

could anyone help me to get the difference between **numb**, **dope**, **anesthetize** and **drug** when we use them as verbs?

explanation with example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The words are all sort of related, though some are more slang-y and others are technical.  I'm going to assume you mean the definitions that relate to each other and not the broader meanings. So, here they are, in order from most technical to least (in my opinion).

**Anesthetize**

This is the technical term for the act of *numbing* a patient before a medical procedure:

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anesthetize):

> medical : to give drugs to (a patient) so that no pain can be felt : to give an anesthetic to (a patient)
>
> *The doctor **anesthetized** the patient [with] an intravenous injection.*

**Numb**

As a verb, this means the same thing as *anesthetize* but it's a non-technical term, often used when talking directly to patients who may not know what the technical term means or by patients who don't want to use the technical term:

[Wictionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/numb#Verb)

> To cause to become numb.
>
> *The dentist gave me Novocaine to **numb** my tooth before drilling, thank goodness.*
>
> *"I'm going to **numb** the area before we get started with the procedure."*

It can also be more generally used, outside of the medical world:

[Oxford Learners](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/numb_2)

> to make a part of your body unable to feel anything, for example because of cold
>
> *His fingers were **numbed** with the cold.*

**Drug**

This is used much more broadly than *anesthetize* because, while anesthetics are a *type* of drug, there are many others. This generally carries a negative connotation, though, so use with caution:

[Oxford Learners](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/drug_2):

> to give a person or an animal a drug, especially to make them unconscious, or to affect their performance in a race or competition
>
> *He was **drugged** and bundled into the back of the car.*
>
> *He was asleep, heavily **drugged** with tranquillizers.*

It could also be used more informally/colloquially:

> *The doctor **drugged** me before the operation and I didn't feel a thing.*

**Dope**

Dope is much more slang, though it's being used more and more in relation to [sports drug use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doping_in_sport). The verb definition is almost identical to *drug*.

[Oxford Learners](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/dope_2):

> to give a drug to a person or an animal in order to affect their performance in a race or sport
>
> *The wine was **doped**.*

It can be used, very informally, in the medical sense:

> *I was so **doped up** on morphine, I don't remember anything that happened.*

Comment: I'll disagree with anesthetize vs numb. To anesthetize means to administer an anesthetic. While a local anesthetic produces numbness, in line with your statement, a general anesthetic causes loss of consciousness.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I agree that *anesthetized* and *numb* **absolutely do not** mean the same thing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anesthesia